# Meteor does see a remote mongodb instance with MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a issue when using a remote mongodb with the new meteor 1.3

```
var d = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<mongo url>");
C = new Mongo.Collection("<collection name>", { _driver: d });
```

I put it in my collections folder like this

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    var driver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/customCollec");
} 
C = new Mongo.Collection("customCollec", { _driver: driver });
```

But on the client side a call like this return me : `C` is not defined

```
console.log("" + C.find().count());
```

So i test the same line like this in my collections.js   :

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    var driver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/customCollec");
    C = new Mongo.Collection("customCollec", { _driver: driver });
    console.log("" + C.find().count());
}
```

But the result is the same : `C` is not defined

In addition my setup is with autopublish and insecure (dev staging)

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i finally figured it out (meteor 1.3, autopublish on)!

In lib/collections.js

```
var database;
if(Meteor.isServer){
    console.log("On collections ");
    database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://user:password@0.0.0.0:27017/db_name");
}

MyRemoteCollection = new Mongo.Collection('db_name', { _driver: database });
```

After this i'm able to get values on client side

```
console.log("MyRemoteCollection count = " + MyRemoteCollection.find().count());
```

Of course it works only when collections is loaded.

'Hope it will help ;)