# how to upload a file in meteor using ostrio files?

Tags: meteor

I am working on meteor application.How can I loop to all files instead of one file in profile template.I have successfully uploaded files.But when I fetch according to documentation then it only fetch only one image.And how can I change the directory of upload??
My profile.js file is:

```
imageFile:function() {
        return Images.findOne();
      }
```

My profile.html:

```
<img src="{{imageFile.link}}" alt="{{imageFile.name}}" />
```

How can I add image info to other database??

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to consider when using this package.

> But when I fetch according to documentation then it only fetch only
>   one image.

1. Your code is returning a cursor to a single file, using [findOne](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/findOne). In order to fetch all files you should use [find](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/find):

```js
imageFiles() {
    return Images.find();
}
```

```html
{{#each imageFiles}}
    <img src="{{this.link}}" alt="{{this.name}}" />
{{/each}}
```

This is basic template work and you should read more about it in the [Blaze documentation](http://blazejs.org/).

2. Images (I assume you followed the Wiki instructions) is not a Mongo.Collection but a FilesCollection. If you want the underlying Mongo. Collection you should reference it via [Images.collection](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/collection).

> And how can I change the directory of upload??

3. To change paths you should check your options, that you pass to the [constructor](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/Constructor), especially `storagePath` and `downloadRoute`.

> How can I add image info to other database??

I assume that you mean that external means on another server or app instance. In this case you need to create a Collection, that uses the Mongo external Driver. How to do that is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374781/3098783).

Just make sure, that you have also access to the public directory and that this collection is a collection that stores Files.

You might ask how to access the FilesCollection from this collection:

```js
const ExternalImages = new FilesCollection({
  collectionName: 'nameOfExternalCollection',
});
```